# retrieve in array from two queries for an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

there are two table in my DBMS (sql server 2012) : pointsBadgeTable and EmployeeTable.

I have made the below ajax call using the below query and is able to retrieve the array successfully.

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "abc";
$connectioninfo = array(
    'Database' => 'novemberLastWeek'
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectioninfo);
if (!$conn) {
    echo 'connection failure';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , TRUE));
}

if(isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])){
  $q1 = "select * from pointsBadgeTable WHERE EmployeeID = '".$_POST['id']."' and WeekNumber='week51' order by pointsRewarded desc";
  // and convert it to JSON like your script above so your javascript does the rest.
  // _+_______________________________________________________________________________--

  if(($stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $q1)) != false){
    do {
      while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
      }
    } while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first// find the code and paste it in there
    echo json_encode($result);
  } else {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); //try
  }
} else {
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
}

?>
```

now I have one more query from the an another table in the same DB :

```
select * from EmployeeTable;
```

ajax call :

```html
$('.leaderboard li').one('click', function () {
   $.ajax({
     url: "../popupData/dataWeekly.php", 
     type: "POST",
     data: {id:$(this).find('.parent-div').data('id')},
     success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      $('#popup').fadeIn();
      $('#managerid').text('Reporting Manager: ' + data[0].ReportingManager);
      $('#popup-name').text('Name: ' + data[0].EmployeeName);
      $('#weeklypoints').text('Recent Weekly Points :'  + data[0].pointsRewarded +' ' +"(" +data[0].WeekNumber+")");
      $('#weeklyrank').text('Recent Weekly Rank :'  + data[0].rank +' ' +"(" +data[0].WeekNumber+")");

      //$('#comment').text('Comment weekly: ' + data[0].Comment);

       $('#gold').text(' ' +  data[0].Gold);
       $('#Silver').text(' ' +  data[0].silver);
       $('#Bronze').text(' ' +  data[0].bronze);

       // etc ..
     },
     error: function(){
       alert('failed, possible script does not exist');
     }
   });
 });
```

How do I include both the queries in the above PHP and fetch the entire info from doth the queries into a single array.

Kindly help.

Comment: Those two tables are related? What's their purpose? Can their data be joined or they absolutely must be returned in two distinct arrays?

Comment: the tables arenot related otherwise I would have used innerjoin and the problem would be solved.I want the data from both the tables  in a single array

Comment: If I use two array ,how would I call like I am doing in the above ajax... just curious

Comment: Yeah that's what I though. :) You can use @Nir Tzezana nested ajax solution, or do you two requests and return a big array containing the two others ans adjust your client-side data processing.

Comment: thats obvious, i know that... but how ? thats what I wanted to know... the data file is the above file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without details how to process the data here's a basic example hot to group in one call two distinct data :

PHP:

```
/*...*/

// Grouping the two vars under the same array.
echo json_encode(array(
    "pointsBadges" => $pointsBadgesData,
    'employees' => $employeesData
));
```

Javascript :

```
$('.leaderboard li').one('click', function () {
   $.ajax({
     url: "../popupData/dataWeekly.php",
     dataType: 'json', // Will automaticaly parse JSON
     type: "POST",
     data: {
        id: $(this).find('.parent-div').data('id')
     },
     success: function(data){
      // For each pointsBadges, do [...]
      $.each(data.pointsBadges, (key, value) => {
        /*...*/
      });

      // For each employees, do [...]
      $.each(data.employees, (key, value) => {
        /*...*/
      });
     },
     error: function(){
       alert('failed, possible script does not exist');
     }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could nest your AJAX requests:

```
$.get("url1.php").done(function(data1){
    $.get("url2.php").done(function(data2){
      // Do whatever you want
    });
});
```